# Outlook Add-In cookies on closing taskpane

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have created an outlook add-in which has a login page and a protected page.
When the user launches the add-in, the protected page is attempted to be loaded, if the user session is not valid the user gets redirected to login page. Once logged in, until the cookie expiration, the user never needs to login again even if the task pane is closed.

This is working as expected in Outlook 15.4. But in Outlook v16.9, the behavior seems having changed.

It looks like when the task pane is closed, the cookies are being cleared out and every time the user tries to open the task pane, the login page is shown. The cookies are http-only set by the server on login.

Is there a workaround to retain the cookies on closing the add-in task pane?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to use [RoamingSettings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/RoamingSettings) object instead. this one design to keep user settings.

Comment: Since the cookie server sets is http-only, I do not have access to this and can't persist the cookie in settings/roaming settings. It's really the behavior difference between v15.4 and v16.9 that's causing this issue.

Comment: I am developing an add-in for Outlook and on a Mac with `16.18` and can verify the same behavior.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. I have an auth server setting http-only cookies, and a new one gets set each time the task pane is opened, triggering a refresh. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did not find a way to prevent clearing out the cookies. I had to change the approach and use OAuth to solve the specific issues for my app. OfficeJS helpers library was useful.