# outlook web addin - cookies are cleared when task pane closed win 10

Tags: cookies, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook web addin, in the taskpane I have a cookie sent from the server with httpOnly. For the same session cookie is handled correctly, when I close the task pane and re-open the cookie seems to be cleared.
This does not happen on Mac, does not happen on Windows when the browser used by outlook is IE11.
Seems to be happening only when the outlook uses edge as it's engine.
Is there something I can add in the manifest perhaps to avoid this cookie clearing?

Comment: I would not rely on a session cookie to persist between Outlook add-in open/close.  I suggest browser local storage or the Office.RoamingSettings to persist information or use API calls.  What is the purpose of the cookie?  Is it to keep some kind of state with the server?  Is it because of a particular web control/component?

Comment: I would like to rely on it as much as I rely on browser open/close so that until I close the outlook at least the session will persist (I would hope for longer but I guess that's pushing it). We have a session cookie coming in that way with httpOnly set. As I mentioned this works on most of the outlook desktop version.

Comment: Unless the Outlook Add-In documentation states, or Microsoft comments that it should persist, it would be a risky assumption especially when building a production solution. What happens if it breaks?  When I was debugging my Outlook desktop add-in by attaching to the IE browser process using Visual Studio, each time the add-in pane would open, there would be a new IE process started.  Is the cookie for auth reasons?  Persistence reasons?  Here the author did OAuth because cookie was used for auth reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706692/outlook-add-in-cookies-on-closing-taskpane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @BrianClink's response, the session cookie probably works on most versions that use Internet Explorer to load the add-ins. Whenever an add-in is closed, Internet Explorer stays alive for a while, which probably preserves the session cookies. Since we switched to Microsoft Edge, this is no longer the case. So please don't rely on this behavior for preserving cookies.

Comment: why would  a browser process being closed delete the cookies of said browser?

Comment: It can depend on the browser and the kind of cookie. Some cookies like HttpOnly cookies and cookies without an expiration date are generally not persisted. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT You've touched on not being able to rely on session cookies, but could you please confirm if persistent httpOnly cookies (i.e. those with a maxAge) will persist through taskpane open/close and Outlook app open/close across all versions of Outlook (Mac, Windows Desktop, Web, Mobile etc)? This does seem to work with my Mac Desktop Outlook App, but I'm cautious to rely on it until I have confirmation.